# Which function gets larger?

Tags: calculus

I am given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I am supposed to figure out which function is eventually greater. I found $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \infty$$ that means the functions eventually diverge. But how am I supposed to figure out which of the two becomes the largest? Btw, the two functions are  $e^{0.1x}$ and $10x^{2}$.

Comment: Presumably, $f(x)=e^{0.1x}$ and $g(x)=10x^2$. Doesn't your limit say it all? For large $x$, $f(x)/g(x)>1$ so $f(x)>g(x)$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: By your limit, for $x$ large, $f(x)/g(x)>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\operatorname{f}(x)/\operatorname{g}(x) \to \ell$ as $x \to \infty$, where $\ell \ge 0$.

- If $\ell = 0$ then $\operatorname{g}(x) \gg \operatorname{f}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.
- If $0 < \ell < 1$ then $\operatorname{g}(x) > \operatorname{f}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.
- If $\ell = 1$ then $\operatorname{g}(x) \to \operatorname{f}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.
- If $1 < \ell <\infty$ then $\operatorname{g}(x)<\operatorname{f}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.
- If $\ell = \infty$ then $\operatorname{g}(x) \ll \operatorname{f}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily, both function may be decreasing but lim can go to infinity for example f(x) = 1/x, and g(x) = (1/x)^2.